# How to prevent other servers from accessing mongodb in amazon?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I thought the way to do it is to

```
delete rules for port 27017

I did that

ICMP
Port (Service)  Source  Action
ALL sg-665f6e34 (default)   Delete
TCP
Port (Service)  Source  Action
0 - 65535   sg-665f6e34 (default)   Delete
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0   Delete
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0   Delete
3306 (MYSQL)    0.0.0.0/0   Delete
5900 - 5910 0.0.0.0/0   Delete
UDP
Port (Service)  Source  Action
```

Yet I can still access my database via mongovue without password.

Is this because of this rule:

```
0 - 65535   sg-665f6e34 (default)   Delete
```

But what is that? What is sg-665f6e34?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you are inside a VPC you'll need to remove the desired port and source from the security group the permission for external connections and your MongoDB server will be accessible only from machines inside your VPC using the local address

2) If you are not using a VPC you'll need to remove the desired port and source from the security group permission for external connections and explicitly add permission to the port and IP you need.

NOTE: opening a port to the source 0.0.0.0/0 opens it to anybody. So in the second case you'll need to change 0.0.0.0/0 to the static IP address of the machine you want to grant access to your mongo db instance.

HTH

Comment: what is VPC? Looks like I got my problem solved. I got to simply wait for a while.

Comment: VPC allows you to create your own virtual private cloud inside Amazon Web Services. http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/